# Tokenize and label text

Tags: python, nlp

Here's a simple scanner, that tokenizes text according to certain rules, and labels the tokens.

1. What is the best way to handle unknown characters, and label them as
   unknown?
2. Is there a recommended way/library to speed things up while
   accomplishing similar results and remaining relatively simple.

*Example:*

```
import re

def alpha(scanner,token):
    return token, 'a'

def numeric(scanner,token):
    return token,'rn'

def punctuation(scanner,token):
    return token, 'p'

def superscript(scanner,token):
    return token, 'sn'

scanner = re.Scanner([
    (u"[a-zA-Z]+", alpha),
    (u"[.,:;!?]", punctuation),
    (u"[0-9]+", numeric),
    (u"[\xb9\u2070\xb3\xb2\u2075\u2074\u2077\u2076\u2079\u2078]", superscript),
    (r"[\s\n]+", None), # whitespace, newline
    ])

tokens, _ = scanner.scan("This is a little test? With 7,9 and 6.")
print tokens
```

*out:*

```
[('This', 'a'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'a'), ('little', 'a'), ('test', 'a'),
 ('?', 'p'), ('With', 'a'), ('7', 'rn'), (',', 'p'), ('9', 'rn'), 
 ('and', 'a'), ('6', 'rn'), ('.', 'p')]
```

*ps!* Defined functions will probably try to categorize the tokens further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `re.Scanner` matches patterns in the order provided. So you can provide a very general pattern at the end to catch "unknown" characters:

```
(r".", unknown)
```

---

```
import re

def alpha(scanner,token):
    return token, 'a'

def numeric(scanner,token):
    return token,'rn'

def punctuation(scanner,token):
    return token, 'p'

def superscript(scanner,token):
    return token, 'sn'

def unknown(scanner,token):
    return token, 'uk'

scanner = re.Scanner([
    (r"[a-zA-Z]+", alpha),
    (r"[.,:;!?]", punctuation),
    (r"[0-9]+", numeric),
    (r"[\xb9\u2070\xb3\xb2\u2075\u2074\u2077\u2076\u2079\u2078]", superscript),
    (r"[\s\n]+", None), # whitespace, newline
    (r".", unknown)
    ])

tokens, _ = scanner.scan("This is a little test? With 7,9 and 6. \xa0-\xaf")
print tokens
```

yields

```
[('This', 'a'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'a'), ('little', 'a'), 
('test', 'a'), ('?', 'p'), ('With', 'a'), ('7', 'rn'), (',', 'p'), 
('9', 'rn'), ('and', 'a'), ('6', 'rn'), ('.', 'p'), ('\xa0', 'uk'), 
('-', 'uk'), ('\xaf', 'uk')]
```

---

Some of your patterns are `unicode`, and one is a `str`. It is true that in Python2 the pattern and the strings to be matched can be either `unicode` or `str`.

However, [in Python3](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html):

> Unicode strings and 8-bit strings cannot be mixed: that is, you cannot
>   match an Unicode string with a byte pattern or vice-versa

It is good practice, therefore, not to mix them, even in Python2.

---

I think your code is wonderfully simple (except for `superscript` regex. Eek!). I don't know of a library which would make it any simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to do something about the superscript :)